# pyramid + ZODB and pagination

Tags: pagination, pyramid, zodb

I've images stored in my pyramid ZODB app. And I've a view that lists all the images, but that makes rendering the page way too long/slow when I've a lot of images, therefore I want them to paginate say, 15 images per page.

I've looked at quite a bit of examples on the web on webhelpers, but all are for SQL, is there a way to use webhelpers with ZODB? or is there some other library for pagination for ZODB?

Comment: You don't need much of an algorithm, do you? How do you currently list the image ids? Just slice that list in batches.

Comment: @MartijnPieters nah, don't think think I'd need an awesome algorithm. Currently I list all the images from ZODB as root['images'].values() and tal:repeat in the view. I'll try slicing. But since the collection of images will grow in time, I'd rather have something like webhelpers to generate the list for me.

Comment: So it's using a dictionary now. `.values()` is just a list in that case. Nothing fancy there! You may want to apply some sorting (dicts are unordered) but webhelpers can be used unaltered to turn that into pages, no problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok, your comment helped a lot there. I've got a basic pagination:

`collection=request.root['images'].values()
 images=Page(collection,page=1,items_per_page=30)`

But it seems I can't generate something like:
`${images.pager(format='$link_first ~2~ $link_last')}`

I get `NotImplementedError: no URL generator available`

Comment: You did not specify a URL generator callback; see the [`paginate` documentation](http://sluggo.scrapping.cc/python/WebHelpers/modules/paginate.html), you are required to specify one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yup, I figured that out after an hour or so after commenting that. But anyways, thank you, you've been a great help to my pyramid skills. :)